# Windows Server 2019 non-owner node cannot see Cluster Name or IP

Tags: sql-server-2019, azure-vm, windows-server-2019

I am trying to build a SQL Server AlwaysOn Availability Group with 2 nodes in Azure. I have created 2 SQL Server VMs and Managed to create a Cluster with both Nodes as members of that cluster.

I have followed the steps in this Article of building the Windows Clusters https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/availability-group-manually-configure-tutorial
with 1 significant change, I used powershell to create the cluster.

```
New-Cluster -Name SQLClusterName -Node ("SQLNode1","SQLNode2") –StaticAddress 172.100.10.100 -NoStorage -ManagementPointNetworkType Singleton
```

Because, if I used Failover Cluster Manager to build the cluster it did not created Cluster Core Resources and I did not gave me the option to select an IP for the cluster.

Anyway, once the cluster has been configured, I tried to configure AlwaysOn Availability Group, but the wizard fails to create Always on Availability Group, complains about it cannot connect to the Cluster.

I went on both Nodes and what I have realised is that I can ping to the Cluster Name or IP and get a response only from the Owner Node. From the cluster Non-owner node I could not ping the cluster name or IP. If I failover the cluster to the 2nd node the I ping behaviour will be contra versa.

Has everyone else experienced this issue? Is so, how you managed to resolve it? Any help or a pointer in the right direction is much appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to fix this by enabling HA ports in the Azure Load Balancer (standard Load Balancer). That seems to have fixed the issue.

By the way I have SQL Server 2019 Enterprise on Windows Server 2019.

Set the following Load Balancing rule in the Azure Load Balancer for WFCS.

[image]

The source of this information for this article : https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-sql/virtual-machines/windows/availability-group-manually-configure-tutorial#add-the-cluster-core-ip-address-for-the-windows-server-failover-cluster-wsfc

The article does not talk about HA ports because it is a Standard Azure Load Balancer feature and the article was written using a Basic  Azure Load Balancer.